# Xcode 11.3 not opening Assets.xcassets file on all my projects

Tags: permissions, xcode11, xcode11.3

After downloading Xcode 11.3 (twice) I keep getting this message when I try to build any of my existing projects: The file “Preview Assets.xcassets” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

I've used "get info" to check the permissions for Assets.xcassets.  Even though the permissions looked good, I changed them again.  I also tried the other solutions for this problem from earlier versions, deleted and re-added the Assets.xcassets files, re-booted my Mac, deleted and reloaded Xcode.

Any ideas what to try next?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Finder Assets.xcassets -> properties -> access rights and access (or how it would be in english). Grant access to read and write for all users
Add all assets in Xcode (if you deleted them). Try to build
If failed, then grand access again.